# Breaking a loop without ending the program (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I have a dictionary with a list of key presses and file names stored in key-value pairs as strings. I want to check if the key pressed is in the dictionary then print the pressed key and the file name associated with it.

My issue is that after I press one key, it keeps looping through the same function and only prints that key. I know I need to stop it from looping, but I don't know how to do that without using "break" or "return" to end the program. The only condition I want the program to end under is if the "esc" key is pressed.

I feel like the answer is ridiculously easy and I'm missing something simple, please help.

Here is my code:

```
import keyboard
import pygame

# there is more in the dictionary, but it's not much different from what is already pasted here
keys = {"`": "sounds/c2.mp3", "1": "sounds/db2.mp3", "2": "sounds/d2.mp3",} 
key = keyboard.read_key()

def sound():
    play = keys.get(key, "")
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def keypress():
    while True:
        if key in keys.keys():
            if key != "esc":
                print(key)
                sound()
            else:
                break

keypress()
```

Comment: Note: `if key in keys.keys()` is true, it **can't also be equal to `"esc"`**. And you never update `key`, so it will always be the same value once you reach the `keypress` function.

Comment: what's your keyboard .py look like?

Comment: You're referring to the import at the top, right? It's this python library: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move `key = keyboard.read_key()` inside your `while` loop.  (Probably just after `while True:`)

Comment: This fixed the issue somewhat. I also had to move the sound() function into the keypress() function because it refers back to the variable "key"

Comment: You should pass the ‘key’ parameter into your ‘sound()’ function.